# Unable to load new data fact table SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I am using visual studios 2017 and Microsoft SQL Studio 17.

While using SSIS I am trying to update the fact table with new data. I am getting an error trying this.

[image]

I have loaded some data (big amount) to the fact table this did not cover all the columns so there is null values. I have another table created with this data (8 rows) that I want to load in and populate it. I have the surrogate key with new table it searches using look up and then goes ahead and adds it. Everything is going fine except into the destination.

Getting this error. All data types match.

> \Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on
>   component "fact to receive" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029
>   while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). The identified
>   component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
>   specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
>   Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.

If I can not trouble shoot this on SSIS would there be a command to run on T SQL you can advise.

Has gone through by assigning surrogate keys to the source table. This does not look like the data has entered successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Theres gotta be some more error message. But try to delete your destination and add it again?

Comment: cheers tried it no joy.

Comment: Then find some more errormessages. Have you tried to put in a dataviewer to see which data comes out?

Comment: If you read your error it says it pretty clearly? Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'newYear_Sk', table - You table has a design where it does NOT ALLOW nulls. And your obviously trying to insert nulls.

Comment: Thanks good suggestion. Iused the look up and added the new surrogate key loaded fine. Still showing null unpopilated for some reason on the fact table at least it went through.I was hoping to get the records update added a screen shot of the fact table.

Comment: ITs because you havent mapped all your columns.